# Why have all my LED bulbs stopped working at once?

Tags: electrical-panel

Prior to today.I had all LED bulbs,everything was working fine.Today none of the LED bulbs were working.I tried changing LEDs with an ordinary lightbulb, and everything worked. I noticed them all to be not as bright as they normally are.Even the light in the fridge looked somewhat dim.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a low voltage situation at the source. Does anyone else in your neighborhood report problems?

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?

Comment: Your circuit has a dimmer somewhere in it, and somebody turned it a bit.  The LEDs are not giving the dimmer a current path to do the thing it needs to do.   Add one incandescent, it breaks the logjam and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where I bought a house with a dimmer on the chandelier. We never used the dimmer portion, but it was one of the old style dimmers and you had to push the dimmer knob in to turn it on. One night, my daughter bumped the knob while turning it on and a LED bulb blew out. It wasn't an expensive bulb thankfully (Black Friday sale), but it still scared her. I replaced it with a standard switch and it's worked fine ever since.

It sounds like you have the non-dimmable LEDs like I do (they're cheaper). Any variance in the voltage could cause this problem (it's how the old-school dimmers did it). Make sure you don't have any stray voltage in your house. This could be a precursor to a wiring problem. As others have mentioned, get a voltmeter or an electrician out to make sure it's not wiring related.

Answer (score 0):

LED lighting is very susceptible to line surges. Without a surge suppressor for the lighting circuit, one surge, even of short duration or relative low peak voltage, it's bye-bye to the LEDs. Test with a new LED in the sockets, it should light signifying that the circuit is still intact.

Comment: I disagree, that's a "cheap" problem.  LEDs have internal electronics, and **build quality matters**.  Cheap bottom shelf junk has cheapened power supplies vulnerable to spikes/surges, but that's not the fault of "LED lighting", it's the fault of the price-motivated shopper with a dysfunctional set of priorities. A quality build will not have that problem.  Also, many "bulbs" are multi-voltage up to 240V, so spikes up to 300V or so are merely considered more useful power.